# how do we access the socket handle inside a boost asio completion handler?

Tags: boost, boost-asio

Is there any possible way to access the socket handle inside a boost asio async completion handler ? i looked at the boost asio placeholders but there is no variable which stores the socket handle.

Answer (score 0):

You can just arrange for it, anyway you would outside boost or asio.

To bind a function that takes e.g. a socket to expose a `void()` function you can use `bind`:

```
int foo(std::string const& s, int);
std::function<void()> adapted = std::bind(foo, "hello world", 42);
```

---

So, usually you'd have code similar to this:

```
boost::asio::async_connect(socket_.lowest_layer(), endpoint_iterator,
    boost::bind(&client::handle_connect, this, boost::asio::placeholders::error));
```

Note, by using bind and `this`, we've bound a member function to the completion handler:

```
struct client
{
    // ....
    void handle_connect(boost::system::error_code err)
    {
        // you can just use `this->socket_` here
        // ...
    }
};
```

This implies that in `handle_connect` we can just use the `socket_` member variable.

However, if you want to make things complicated you can use free functions as well

```
boost::asio::async_connect(socket_.lowest_layer(), endpoint_iterator,
    boost::bind(&free_handle_connect, boost::ref(socket_), boost::asio::placeholders::error));
```

Now the implied handler function looks like

```
static void free_handle_connect(
    boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket& socket_,
    boost::system::error_code err)
{
    // using `socket_` as it was passed in
    int fd = _socket.native_handle_type();
}
```

Comment: You probably meant `native_handle()` (instead of `lowest_layer()`).

Comment: In fact, I didn't. I forgot to mention `native_handle_type()` (although I'm not convinced that was the _actual thing_ that the OP was after). I'll consider it mentioned now, and a link to the docs: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/basic_stream_socket/native_handle_type.html

Comment: my problem is that i have to use a static member function which does not have a this pointer and i need to identify the fd or boost socket handle for which the static member function is being called. hope that is clear.

Comment: @RavikumarTulugu in that case, `free_handle_connect` is the example that matches your situation